# How to merge 2 Python dataframes with different columns but possible same datetime index avoiding index duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes that with different column names and indexed by datetime:

df1

```
            A  B
time            
2011-03-01  1  6
2011-03-02  4  8
2011-03-08  5  2
2011-03-09  6  3
```

df2

```
            C  D
time            
2011-03-01  8  7
2011-03-02  9  6
2011-03-07  4  4
2011-03-08  1  2
```

I want to merge them to obtain something like this:

```
            A  B  C  D
time                          
2011-03-01  1  6  8  7
2011-03-02  4  8  9  3
2011-03-07  NaN  NaN  4  4
2011-03-08  5  2  1  2
2011-03-09  6  3  NaN  NaN
```

instead using the *concat* command:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort_index()
```

I get the following merged dataframe:

```
              A    B    C    D
time                          
2011-03-01  1.0  6.0  NaN  NaN
2011-03-01  NaN  NaN  8.0  7.0
2011-03-02  4.0  8.0  NaN  NaN
2011-03-02  NaN  NaN  9.0  6.0
2011-03-07  NaN  NaN  4.0  4.0
2011-03-08  5.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
2011-03-08  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0
2011-03-09  6.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

with undesired duplicated indexes!

How can I merge the 2 DFs properly?

Comment: Take a look at [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: You code is fine, but use `axis=1`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71174264/16343464).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.concat` is the way to go, using **`axis=1`**.

If you still have issues with `axis=1`, then this means your indexes don't align (maybe a different type) and you will have the same issue with `join` or `merge`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4,5,6], 'B': [6,8,2,3]},
                   index=['2011-03-01', '2011-03-02', '2011-03-08', '2011-03-09'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [8,9,1,4], 'D': [7,6,2,4]},
                   index=['2011-03-01', '2011-03-02', '2011-03-07', '2011-03-08'])

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index()
```

output:

```
              A    B    C    D
2011-03-01  1.0  6.0  8.0  7.0
2011-03-02  4.0  8.0  9.0  6.0
2011-03-07  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0
2011-03-08  5.0  2.0  4.0  4.0
2011-03-09  6.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.merge`

```
pd.merge(
    df1, # Your first df 
    df2, # Second df
    how="outer", 
    left_index=True, # merging on index (your datetime)
    right_index=True, # mergin on index (your datetime)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not access your dataframe to check my code, but here what I have come up with:

```py
import numpy as np
df2.reset_index().merge(df1.reset_index(), on="time").fillna(np.NAN)
```

##### Explanation

You need to call `reset_index()` to change the index to a column. If you are not interested to do so, you can use `left_index` and `right_index` parameters in the `merge` function.